# Problema al correr aplicación en visual basic

Tags: vb.net

> Excepción no controlada del tipo 'Microsoft.VisualBasic.ApplicationServices.NoStartupFormException' en Microsoft.VisualBasic.dll

me marca ese error y me parece un mensaje el cual dice: La aplicación se encuentra en modo de interrupción

Comment: hola, por favor mira [ask]. se ve que tu proyecto no es de consola y no tienes un formulario de inicio (eso dice el error) pero sin saber que haces, dificil contestar algo.

Answer (score 0):

En las propiedades del proyecto asegúrate que en la pestaña *Application* en el combo *Startup form* se encuentra alguno seleccionado.

Ese formulario será el que se mostrará al iniciar la aplicación.

Answer (score 0):

Debes verificar en tu proyecto que el formulario o la clase de inicio se encuentre disponible y con el mismo nombre que el indicas en tu clase Main.

Answer (score 0):

Cambia el destino de la plataforma a X86 en las propiedades del proyecto.
Si borras las carpetas BIN y OBJ no estará de mas.
Estas carpetas se regeneran solas. 
Suerte, esta tontería me ha llevado 3 horas comparando un proyecto backup con el que me fallaba y no me  consta haberlo cambiado yo.